# What are the different ways to creating template for a website from scratch?

Tags: website-design, html5, responsive-webdesign, template, software

I would like to know the different ways we can create template for a website because many times the pre-made templates available online don't fit to the requirements of everybody.

The style I want for my website isn't available online, so please tell the ways to create template.

1. Are there any softwares that are used to create them where you can just drag and drop the elements?
2. Or we can create it with coding? ( By coding I mean HTML + CSS) *[if anything else is required then correct me!]*

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic on this site. And both of your questions heavily depend on many factors. It's similar to asking "Are there any cake mixes out there, or can we create a cake using flour?"

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister ok, can you tell me if we can create template using html and CSS?

Comment: yes, you can do that.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister ok thanks